# R Multiple Line Graph for MLB Team Wins by Year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make it so that there is a line for each team, with the color of that line matching the color in the legend. I wrote the program as if it were a bar chart, since I know how to do that, so I think there are only a few changes that need to be made in order to make it into lines. Note: I don't want a line of best fit, but rather, one that connects from dot to dot.

This next part may be very time consuming, so I don't expect any one to help with this, but I would also really like to have the team logos in the legend, maybe replacing the team names. Then in the legend, I would like to have the color associated with the team as a line rather than a box.

Any help with either or both of these would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: I would like to keep all the features that the program below has, such as the gray background, white grids, ect.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Year  Orioles RedSox Yankees Rays BlueJays
  1998   79       92      114    63    88
  1999   78       94      98     69    84
  2000   74       85      87     69    83
  2001   63       82      95     62    80
  2002   67       93      103    55    78 
  2003   71       95      101    63    86
  2004   78       98      101    70    67
  2005   74       95      95     67    80
  2006   70       86      97     61    87
  2007   69       96      94     66    83
  2008   68       95      89     97    86
  2009   64       95      103    84    75
  2010   66       89      95     96    85
  2011   69       90      97     91    81
  2012   93       69      95     90    73
  2013   85       97      85     92    74
  2014   96       71      84     77    83
  2015   81       78      87     80    93
  2016   89       93      84     68    89'), header = TRUE)



df %>% 
  gather(Team, Wins, -Year) %>% 
  mutate(Team = factor(Team, c("Orioles", "RedSox", "Yankees","Rays","BlueJays"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Wins)) +
  ggtitle("AL East Wins") +
  ylab("Wins") +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Team), position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "red", "blue", "black","purple"))+ 
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = "white")
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_path(aes(color = Team))` instead of `geom_col(aes(fill = Team)` and a named color palette to achieve your basic goals like this:

```
# break this off the pipeline
df <- gather(df, Team, Wins, -Year) %>% 
    mutate(Team = factor(Team, c("Orioles", "RedSox", "Yankees","Rays","BlueJays")))

# if you want to resuse the same theme a bunch this is nice
# theme_grey() is the default theme
theme_set(theme_grey() +
              theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
                    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
                    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray")))

# named palettes are easy
# for specific colors i like hex codes the best
# i just grabbed these of this nice website TeamColorCodes, could be fun!
cust <- c("#FC4C00", "#C60C30", "#1C2841", "#79BDEE","#003DA5")
names(cust) <- levels(df$Team)

# use geom_path inplace of geom_col
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Wins, color = Team)) +
    geom_path(aes(color = Team)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = cust) +
    labs(title = "AL East Wins",
         subtitle = "Ahhh",
         y = "Wins",
         x = "Year")
```

[Link to teamcolorcodes.com](http://teamcolorcodes.com/toronto-blue-jays-color-codes/%20%22)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also, how can I make a line light blue? I tried changing it from "blue" to blue(.3) but got an error

Comment: Also, everything looks great but the only other thing I would like is grid lines, maybe with the color white.

Comment: I'm definitely going to check that website out for the colors, thanks.